# How can I enable system configuration values that are disabled

Tags: magento2, system-config

In the magento backend under stores->configuration,  I can't edit most of the system settings anymore. Usually I was able to uncheck "use system value" and then change the corresponding value as I needed.

I don't know what I did to change this behavior, but now I get the denied cursor when I hover over the "use system value" checkbox, and the checkbox itself is greyed out (uneditable).

How can I edit these values again?

edit 1: I'm on Magento 2.2.0, store view is "Default Config"

edit 2: This only seems to affect the "Default Config" settings. When I switch over to "Main Website" I can change the system settings. This is acceptable as a workaround for now, but I would love to know what's going on here so I can avoid it next time!

[image: screenshot of disabled settings]
[image: picture of mouse cursor over settings]

Comment: Currently you are in which scope in admin?

Comment: What's your Magento version ?